Determine thermal emissivity of material
Is there a practical way of determining it without a lab setup?
interested in Aluminum alloys ADC-10 and ADC-12

Does searching online for something like thermal emissivity of aluminum adc-## count as "determining it without a lab setup"?

It is A380 aluminum alloy and commonly used for manufacturing die castings. It is also one of the most very widely used and specified alloys that have very many substantial benefits. In addition, to use in hundreds of thousands of applications, it carries significant mechanical properties. I don't think it is possible to determine its emission rates.

At what wavelength? I don't see a well formed question here to begin with.

Some IR thermometric probes have an adjustment for the emissivity of the surface you want to measure the temperature of.
What you do then is heat that surface to a known temperature (measured by some other means), aim the probe at it, and adjust the emissivity until the measured temperatures match up.
